# What FLOSS skype alternatives are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, skype

Given Skype's slow development speed for the GNU/Linux version and its recent acquisition by Microsoft, I am looking for alternative softwares.

What [FLOSS (free/libre/open-source software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open_source_software) Skype alternatives are available?

Comment: Is dialing to normal phones a requirement for you?

Comment: @Nicolas raoul it is preferable but not a requirement.

Comment: Don't you mean FOSS? What does FLOSS stand for?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOSS

Comment: @Marco Ceppi free/libre/open-source software .

Comment: What features does the alternative provide? I'm thinking about chat, voice, conference call, video call and screen share. How does they handle strange firewalls i.e. in a hotel or behind a "big corp." firewall.

Comment: upvoting because 69 sounds pr0n.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

## SIP Clients

These all are SIP clients which means they all can be used to call each other and they just need a SIP address (like your mobile number). You can get a SIP address for free from many providers ([Ekiga](https://www.ekiga.net/?page=register), [jit.si](http://jit.si), [iptel](http://www.iptel.org)), some of which ([sip2sip.info](http://sip2sip.info), [ippi.com](http://www.ippi.com), [localphone.com](http://www.localphone.com/), [nonoh.net](http://nonoh.net)) also have PSTN gateways into the normal phone network which allows you to make and receive regular calls from/to your SIP client (for a fee). For various reasons some clients may not work with some providers (for example, for Nonoh and Iptel, Blink works but Jitsi, Ekiga, and Linphone don't).

[Ekiga](http://www.ekiga.org/) (available in the software center)

[Here is First use documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ekiga#First%20use) for ekiga .

[Here is documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ekiga#Register%20to%20a%20commercial%20VoIP%20provider%20%28landline%20and%20mobile%20phones%29) on how to use the PC to Phone feature in ekiga .

> Ekiga (formely known as GnomeMeeting) is an open source SoftPhone, Video Conferencing and Instant Messenger application over the Internet.

[Ring](https://ring.cx/) (available in the software center)

> Ring is free software for universal communication which respects freedoms and privacy of its users. It supports SIP accounts. Ring is available under the GNU GPL license, version 3.

[Twinkle](http://www.twinklephone.com/)  (available in the software center)

> Twinkle is a softphone for your voice over IP and instant messaging communcations using the SIP protocol. You can use it for direct IP phone to IP phone communication or in a network using a SIP proxy to route your calls and messages.

[Yate VoIP](http://yate.null.ro/pmwiki/) (available in the software center)

> YATE is a telephony engine aimed at creating a telephony server that performs well enough to deal with PBX requirements and also flexible enough for complex Gateway and IVR solutions.
>
> YateClient uses the same telephony code to produce a software desktop VoIP (SIP, H.323, IAX2) phone. yate-qt4 uses this to provide such a telephony

[QuteCom](http://trac.qutecom.org/wiki/QuteCom)  (available in the software center)

> QuteCom is a community of enthusiasts and developers, creating free software products related to communication over IP. The flagship product of the QuteCom project is a softphone which allows you to make free PC to PC video and voice calls, and to integrate all your IM contacts in one place.

[Linphone](http://www.linphone.org/) (available in the software center)

> Linphone is an internet phone or Voice Over IP phone (VoIP).
> With linphone you can communicate freely with people over the internet,
> with voice, video, and text instant
> messaging.
> Linphone makes use of the SIP protocol , an open standard for
> internet telephony. You can use
> Linphone with any SIP VoIP operator,
> including our free SIP audio/video
> service

[Jitsi](http://jitsi.org/)

> Jitsi - Open Source Video Calls and Chat
> Secure video calls, conferencing, chat, desktop sharing, file transfer, support for your favorite OS, and IM network. All this, and more, in Jitsi - the most complete and advanced open source communicator. Implemented in Java.

[Blink](http://icanblink.com/index.phtml)

> A state of the art, easy to use SIP client
> Available for Mac, Windows and Linux. Comprehensive controls over the details of the protocol. Blink is the end-result of cumulated knowledge built over many years by its developers who worked on the development of popular open-source SIP infrastructure software and attended relevant IETF and SIPIT events where SIP protocol has been developed and tested [18](http://icanblink.com/credits.phtml).  Implemented using Qt.

Comment: Also, it is possible to call normal phones from an sip gateway.  Localphone.com is a good example, but there are many others.  Another example is SIPSorcery, which can be used to connect to many services.

Comment: But on the con side, you don't have a contact list, like with skype

Comment: @JochenJung o really? http://www.ekiga.org/sites/all/themes/ekiga_net/images/Address_Book.png

Comment: with this many clients I think this should be turned into a community wiki answer with each client being an individual answer

Comment: What about Mumble??
http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 19):

You can use Empathy (pre-installed in Ubuntu) instead of Skype.

For users of Windows, OS/X, you can ask them to install Google Voice and Video chat, http://www.google.com/chat/video

Empathy and Google Voice and Video chat are compatible with each other, so you can have voice and video chats!

There is an option for VoIP (SIP) support in Empathy. You install the `telepathy-sofiasip` package to add SIP support. It might not be excellent yet, however you can get the work done.

In addition, with Empathy you have many additional options (not found in basic Skype), including

- you have the option for remote desktop to your IM contacts (pre-installed)
- you can SSH to the computer of your contacts (requires package to install)
- you can collaborate with your contacts in writing a document with `gedit` (see `gedit-collaborate`).

Comment: How do you set the telepathy plugin to use Ekiga?

Comment: There was an attempt to get Ekiga to work with Telepathy (part of Google Summer of Code), but it appears it did not work out (google for it for more).

Answer (score 7):

[**TOX**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tox_%28software%29#Features) is an open source project to build a code library establishing a messaging and video calling protocol, started with user privacy in mind. It provides and API, or core, around which user front-ends, or clients, can be built.

There are three Tox clients in development for Linux:

. [**Venom**](https://github.com/naxuroqa/Venom) - a cross-platform graphical user interface for Tox written in Vala using GTK+. [Install instructions](https://wiki.tox.im/Venom).

. [**Blight**](https://github.com/lehitoskin/Blight) - a cross-platform graphical user interface for Tox written in Racket that utilizes libtoxcore-racket. In very early pre-alpha stage.

. [**Qt GUI for Tox**](https://github.com/nurupo/ProjectTox-Qt-GUI) - a cross-platform front end for Tox Core written in Qt5 and C++. Development is in very early stages and usage beyond testing is not advised.

Answer (score 1):

Not FLOSS but you can use [Googles Voice and Video chat](http://www.google.com/chat/video) from within the browser.

Comment: -1, the heading specifically says "FLOSS".

Comment: ...and it's only available in the USA.

Comment: @Piskvor: was the last time you checked in like in 2007?

Comment: @vartec: 2010; I am unable to find anything official newer than this though: http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2010/06/google-voice-for-everyone.html - note the 'Update' at the end. Yes, I'm aware you can fake all kinds of checks, but some people may need fully legit solutions.

Comment: @vartec: Update: the last time I checked was today, 2011-05-12. Nope, still not available outside the USA.

Comment: @Piskvor: you're talking about completely different product -- Google Voice for Mobile. Click the link from the answer.

Comment: @vartec: Aha, that's interesting: the plugin does work, even though the official blogs (both of [Google Voice](http://googlevoiceblog.blogspot.com/2010/06/google-voice-for-everyone.html) and [Google Voice Mobile](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2010/06/google-voice-for-everyone.html)) say Google Voice (without specifying "for Mobile") only available in the US. I'm *slightly* confused by this, to say the least.

Comment: @Piskor: Google works computer to computer for voice and video outside the US (I've used it). You can only connect to the phone network in the US, though.

Comment: @Piskvor: right, the product binW is writing about is actually called "Google Voice and Video Chat", and you're looking at "Google Voice"

Answer (score 1):

The most popular tool is [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/). It is an *Encrypted text, voice, and video messaging for multiple platforms*.

[image: logo]

More from the [home page](https://jitsi.org/):

> Jitsi (formerly SIP Communicator) is an audio/video and chat
>   communicator that supports protocols such as SIP, XMPP/Jabber,
>   AIM/ICQ, Windows Live, Yahoo! and many other useful features.

You can find more Free Software alternatives to Close Systems on [PRISM BREAK](https://prism-break.org).